# How should I scale this PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was given as exercise to non dimensionalize this [PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgKaE.jpg)
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = -u \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} + D \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}$$

$C$ denotes the concetration per unit volume, so has units [M/L^3], $t$ denotes time, so has units [T], $u$ is the constant velocity in the $x$ directions so has units [L/T], and finally $D$ is the dispersion coefficient with units [L^2/T].
I do not know where to start, because if I let $C$ = [units]$C^*$,... etc. I end up with the same equation, just without $u$ and $k$.

Comment: You should end up with the same equation without the parameters $u, D$. This means that whatever solution you get to the non-dimensional variant can then be scaled appropriately to solve the dimensional versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the non-dimensional quantities $C^*, t^*, x^*$ be as follows
$$
C = C_c C^*, x = \dfrac{D}{u}x^*, t = \dfrac{D}{u^2}t^*
$$

one can pretty easily show that all these terms have the appropriate dimensional units. Now plug these into the PDE

$$
\dfrac{C_c}{\frac{D}{u^2}}\dfrac{\partial C^*}{\partial t^*} = -u \dfrac{C_c}{\frac{D}{u}}\dfrac{\partial C^*}{\partial x^*} + D \dfrac{C_c}{\frac{D^2}{u^2}}\dfrac{\partial^2 C^*}{\partial {x^*}^2}
$$

Now canceling out $\frac{u^2C_c}{D}$ on each side we get

$$
\dfrac{\partial C^*}{\partial t^*} = -\dfrac{\partial C^*}{\partial x^*} + \dfrac{\partial^2 C^*}{\partial {x^*}^2}
$$

which is the non-dimensional scaled version of your PDE. This means that you can solve this general PDE that has no parameters, and then scale the solution you find afterwards to match the given params.